# Elegant way to SELECT a fraction satisfying a WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with the following schema:

{playerId, playSessionLength, timestamp}

I'm would like to find, within some time range, the percentage of play sessions that are less than 10 seconds.

I know how to do this ugly, with two queries:

```
select count(*) from playData where timestamp > start and timestamp < end
select count(*) from playData where timestamp > start and timestamp < end and playSessionLength < 10
```

And then doing the division of B / A.

My question is, what is the cleanest, most elegant way to do this with a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
select 100*count(case when playSessionLength < 10 then 1 else null end)/count(*)
from   playData
where  timestamp > start and timestamp < end
```

... but lookout for count(*) = 0

Comment: "case when" I had no idea this was a keyword. Awesome!

Comment: Avoiding division by zero could be RDBMS-specific syntax. For example in PostgreSQL you'd use NullIf(count(*),0)